# Draw elements from a multiple depth dictionary

Tags: python

Suppose a multiple depth dict

```
{'definition': 'dirname',
 'get': ['getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize'],
 'operation': ['join',
               {'split':['split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext']},
               {'expand': ['expanduser', 'expandvars']},
               ],
}
```

I tried to extract its items with a definded function.

```
lst = []
def count_d(dt):
    global lst # global is unnecessary here
    if isinstance(dt, dict):
        for value in dt.values():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                lst.append(value)
            else:
                count_d(value)
    elif isinstance(dt,list):
        for ele in dt:
            if isinstance(ele, str):
                lst.append(ele)
            else:
                count_d(ele)
    return lst
```

The over_complicated recursive function solved the problem.

```
Out[121]: 
['dirname',
 'getatime',
 'getctime',
 'getmtime',
 'getsize',
 'join',
 'split',
 'splitdrive',
 'splitext',
 'expanduser',
 'expandvars']
```

What I am expecting is:

```
lst = []
def count_d(dt):
    global lst
    for ele in dt:
        if isinstance(ele,str):
            lst.append(ele)
```

or more abstract in one line without declaring variable and using global.

Comment: Could you write exactly what you want the output to be?
Is it just one array of strings, with all key information lost:
['dirname', 'getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize', 'join', 'split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext', 'expanduser', 'expandvars']

Comment: Yes @LukasAnsteeg

Comment: Is it important that the output list is in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using `regex`

```
import re

j=[]
y1 = re.compile("(?<=')[^']+(?='[,|\]$])")
for value in y1.findall(str(dt)):
    j.append(value)
print(j)
```

Output

```
['dirname', 'getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize', 'join', 'split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext', 'expanduser', 'expandvars']
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive code to get **all elements** from the `dictionary`

```
def traverse(d): 
     for k, v in d.items(): 
        if isinstance(v, dict): 
            traverse(v) 
        else: 
            print(k,':',v) 

#traverse(d)
```

#driver values

```
IN : 
d = {'definition': 'dirname', 
     'get': ['getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize'], 
     'operation': ['join', 
                    {'split': ['split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext']}, 
                    {'expand': ['expanduser', 'expandvars']}
                  ]
}

OUT :
definition : dirname
get : ['getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize']
operation : ['join', 
               {'split': ['split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext']}, 
               {'expand': ['expanduser', 'expandvars']}
            ]
```

**EDIT :** As per specification, to get **all values** from a dictionary, a general recursive method:

```
l=[]

def traverse(d): 
     for k, v in d.items():
        print(k,':',v)

        if type(v)==list:                    #since may be a list
            for ele in v:                    #access the list
                if type(ele) == dict:        #since list may contain another dict
                    traverse(ele)
                else:                        #normal values inside the list 
                    l.append(ele)
                    continue

        elif isinstance(v, dict):            #if the value is a dict
            traverse(v)
        else:                                #normal value
            l.append(v)

traverse(d)
print(l)
```

#driver values :

```
OUT: l = ['dirname', 
          'getatime', 
          'getctime', 
          'getmtime', 
          'getsize', 
          'join', 
          'split', 
          'splitdrive', 
          'splitext', 
          'expanduser', 
          'expandvars']
```

Comment: failed to enclose them in one list.

Comment: Just append the values to another `list`

Comment: more complicated~

Comment: Um, how is that complicated??? I'll change and put up the whole code then.

Comment: @DFK , have edited, though I don't think I need have done so.

Comment: want Output: 
['dirname',
 'getatime',
 'getctime',
 'getmtime',
 'getsize',
 'join',
 'split',
 'splitdrive',
 'splitext',
 'expanduser',
 'expandvars']

Comment: @DFK , check now. Though, the recursion is a bit ugly, since it has to deal with a `list` which may contain `dict` , but this should do

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is fine, since you want to extract specific data from both dictionaries and arrays.

A slightly shorter version could be this, but I suppose it's still not as 'elegant' as hoped:

```
def count_d(dt):
    lst = []
    dt_values = dt.values() if isinstance(dt, dict) else dt
    for value in dt_values:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            lst.append(value)
        else:
            lst.extend(count_d2(value))
    return lst
```

The advantage of this function is that it doesn't need you to create a global array, so you can call:

```
data = {'definition': 'dirname',
        'get': ['getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize'],
        'operation': ['join',
                      {'split':['split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext']},
                      {'expand': ['expanduser', 'expandvars']},
        ],
    }

print(count_d(data))

# ['dirname', 'join', 'split', 'splitdrive', 'splitext', 'expanduser', 'expandvars', 'getatime', 'getctime', 'getmtime', 'getsize']
```